# How can I get items from DynamoDB in reverse-chronological order?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using the Javascript AWS SDK to query a DynamoDB table.

I have a table which stores 'applications'. Each application has a primary key (hash key?) of `id`.

Each item also stores `applicationTime` as a datetime string, such as `2018-05-21T19:22:50.884Z`.

I'd like to return the most recent ten applications based on `applicationTime`.

So far, I've got:

```
db.batchGet({
    TableName: 'Applications',
    Limit: 10,
    ScanIndexForward: false,
}, (err, data ) => {
        err ? console.log(err, err.stack) : console.log(data)
})
```

The documentation isn't very novice-friendly and [seems to suggest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.SecondaryIndexes) that I might need a local secondary index in order to sort by `applicationTime`.

However, it's very clear that creating a local secondary index is only possible when the table is initially created. This is a production database so very keen to avoid remaking the table.

This is ludicrously difficult compared to every other database product I've used (SQL and noSQL).

Surely I'm missing something obvious?

*PS. This for an admin-facing tool that will only see occasional use, rather than a core user-facing feature, so I'll settle for an inefficient solution (eg. a scan) if that's the only option.*

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you cannot use local indexes as they are created at the table creating time. So, you options are either global index or scan.

#### Scan

That's simple. Sorting for scans is not supported, so you just get all the data and sort it in the app.

#### GSI

Having an index simplifies the task. The only question is what hash / sort pair to use? According to the great ["Best Practices for Handling Time-Series Data in DynamoDB"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-time-series.html) guide you can do a trick and split the date into date and time pair and then use date as hash key and time as sort key. Doing this will require changes in `applicationTime` handling parts of your app, but the impact does not seem to be horrifying. Then you can use queries on that index to get latest apps. But if you have less then 10 apps per day you'll need to do several queries, though.

---

> This is ludicrously difficult compared to every other database product I've used (SQL and noSQL).

That's true!